# Facebook API Delete Post - App Not Authorized

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to schedule, edit and delete posts on a fan page.

I'm able to create and update posts just fine, but trying to use the DELETE endpoint gives me this response:

***'Application does not have the capability to make this API call'***

The confusing thing is that the same exact call with the same access token works in the API Explorer.

```
HTTP.call('DELETE', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/' + fbId + '?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
```

Comment: was the post created by the same app?

Comment: Yes it was created by the same app